# How to do MVC 4 routing with arguments and defaults

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url, routes, url-routing

This is my default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

My controller is "Home" and my view is "Index" and it takes these arguments with defaults:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string Queue = "ALL", string Summary = "false")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My current URL looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/?Queue=ONE&Summary=true
```

But I would like it to be routed to something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/ONE?Summary=true
```

Basically routing it so I don't have to use the Queue keyword in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your route definition like below,

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{Queue}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", Queue = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: This will works when we use full URL. It will not work in case controller name and action name is not explicitly specified in URL (as specified by OP http://www.example.com/ONE?Summary=true), am i missing something?

Comment: You are correct. It didn't work as described, but I tried this change -> url: "{Queue}" (removing {controller}/{action}/) and it worked :-)